# Should the kaplan meier curve of an training data match the kaplan meier curve from the output of a Weibull AFT model?

Tags: survival, prediction, kaplan-meier

I am running a Weibull AFT model for survival prediction. I am considering the predicted median value as expected Lifetime/output. To check if its following the same decay of out original user, I am comparing the Kaplan meier curve of  the input training data and the model output/expected Lifetime. I was hoping that they should match in shape if not identical.[image]

The blue line is the training data while the orange line is the model output. As you can see after month 5 ,the training/original data is showing more churn than model output.Also churn rate decreases after 20th month while our model doesn't show any sign of decrease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your proposed procedure is not valid. Here's a quick simulation to demonstrate. Below, we make the simulation as *simple* as possible, and the procedure still fails:

1. We'll generate Weibull distributed data, and use a Weibull model to fit. We'll check the fitted parameters are accurate.
2. We'll have *no* censoring.
3. We'll use lots of samples.

```py
from lifelines import WeibullAFTFitter
from scipy.stats import weibull_min

N = 1000                      # sample size
D = 10                        # dimensions
Beta = np.random.randn(D)     # coefficients
X = 0.1 * np.random.randn(N, D)
W = weibull_min.rvs(1.7, scale=0.5, loc=0, size=N)
Y = np.dot(X, Beta)+ np.log(W)
T_actual = np.exp(Y)

df = pd.DataFrame(X)
df['T'] = T_actual

waft = WeibullAFTFitter().fit(df, "T")

# should be near 0.5 and 1.7
print(waft.summary.loc[('rho_','_intercept'), 'exp(coef)'])
print(waft.summary.loc[('lambda_','_intercept'), 'exp(coef)'])
```

Our model is perfectly fitting to the data. Now let's try your procedure:

```py
medians = waft.predict_median(df)

ax = KaplanMeierFitter().fit(df['T'], label="KMF observed times").plot()
ax = KaplanMeierFitter().fit(medians, label="KMF median predictions").plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

Does this look familiar? Same pattern as what you observe.

The problem is that the median biases the prediction towards the "center" of the survival distribution. But individual lifetimes are sampled from the *entire* survival distribution.

If you are interested in a method of calibration, there is the new `survival_probability_calibration` [method](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Survival%20Regression.html#model-probability-calibration).

Comment: Could this also exist for the restricted mean survival time as well (i.e., not just median)? See example below. Also question is posted here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/621138/should-the-kaplan-meier-curve-of-an-training-data-match-the-kaplan-meier-curve-f

Answer (score 0):

Could this also exist for the restricted mean survival time as well (i.e., not just median)? See example below.

Related to: [Should the kaplan meier curve of an training data match the kaplan meier curve from the output of a Weibull AFT model? medians vs rmst](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/621138/should-the-kaplan-meier-curve-of-an-training-data-match-the-kaplan-meier-curve-f)

```py
from lifelines import WeibullAFTFitter, KaplanMeierFitter
from scipy.stats import weibull_min
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 1000  # sample size
D = 10  # dimensions
Beta = np.random.randn(D)  # coefficients
X = 0.1 * np.random.randn(N, D)
W = weibull_min.rvs(1.7, scale=0.5, loc=0, size=N)
Y = np.dot(X, Beta) + np.log(W)
T_actual = np.exp(Y)

df = pd.DataFrame(X)
df['T'] = T_actual

waft = WeibullAFTFitter().fit(df, "T")
medians = waft.predict_median(df)
pred_surv = waft.predict_survival_function(df).T
rmst = np.trapz(y=pred_surv.to_numpy(), x=pred_surv.columns.values)

ax = KaplanMeierFitter().fit(df['T'], label="KMF observed times").plot()
ax = KaplanMeierFitter().fit(medians, label="KMF median predictions").plot(
    ax=ax)
ax = KaplanMeierFitter().fit(rmst, label="KMF RMST predictions").plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Session info

```py
import reprexpy
print(reprexpy.SessionInfo())
#> Session info --------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Platform: macOS-12.0.1-x86_64-i386-64bit (64-bit)
#> Python: 3.8
#> Date: 2023-07-11
#> Packages ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> lifelines==0.27.7
#> matplotlib==3.3.3
#> numpy==1.24.4
#> pandas==1.1.5
#> reprexpy==0.3.2
#> scipy==1.10.1
```