# Should the kaplan meier curve of an training data match the kaplan meier curve from the output of a Weibull AFT model? medians vs rmst

Tags: survival, kaplan-meier

[Should the kaplan meier curve of an training data match the kaplan meier curve from the output of a Weibull AFT model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/473393/should-the-kaplan-meier-curve-of-an-training-data-match-the-kaplan-meier-curve-f)

This question is referring to the linked question above. The accepted answer explained that there's a bias toward the median output so the Kaplan Meier curve from the output doesn't match with the training data Kaplan Meier curve.

However, when I use Restricted Mean Survival Time (rmst), which doesn't have the bias toward the median output since it's not computing the medians but the area under the curve of the individual predicted survival curve. I still observe the same issue that the original poster encountered, i.e, the curves don't match. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

```py
from lifelines import WeibullAFTFitter
from scipy.stats import weibull_min
import numpy as np

N = 1000                      # sample size
D = 10                        # dimensions
Beta = np.random.randn(D)     # coefficients
X = 0.1 * np.random.randn(N, D)
W = weibull_min.rvs(1.7, scale=0.5, loc=0, size=N)
Y = np.dot(X, Beta) + np.log(W)
T_actual = np.exp(Y)

df = pd.DataFrame(X)
df['T'] = T_actual

waft = WeibullAFTFitter().fit(df, "T")
medians = waft.predict_median(df)
pred_surv = waft.predict_survival_function(df).T
rmst = np.trapz(y=pred_surv.to_numpy(), x=pred_surv.columns.values)

ax = KaplanMeierFitter().fit(df['T'], label="KMF observed times").plot()
ax = KaplanMeierFitter().fit(medians, label="KMF median predictions").plot(ax=ax)
ax = KaplanMeierFitter().fit(rmst, label="KMF RMST predictions").plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]